# jQuery blur with an exception

Tags: jquery, css, focus, blur

I have set a focus event on an input element. When there is a focus, jQuery searches for a div and displays it. That works. Wit the blur event on the same input element I make the div hide, which also works. But when I click on a link or want to select text in the shown div, it immediately disappears because of the blur event. How can i make an exception for the shown div?

```
$("input.search-main-text").focus(function() {
    $("div.quickResults").show();
});

$("input.search-main-text").blur(function() {
    $("div.quickResults").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input.search-main-text").bind('focus', function() {
    $("div.quickResults").show();
    $(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
        if (! $(e.target).closest('div.quickResults').length) {
            $("div.quickResults").hide();
            $(document).unbind('mousedown', arguments.callee);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like:

1. Bind the event handler for focus
2. On focus, bind the event handler for blur + event handler for mouseenter on the shown div
3. On mouseenter on the shown div, unbind the blur event from the input field
4. On mouseleave / other suitable event on the shown div, re-bind the blur event listener to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I cannot tell you much, just that if I were you I'd try to use the **change** event on the text input element rather than focus and blur. If you describe more what you're trying to implement I may be able to be more specific.